# Custom icon doesn't show up in Intellij Actions

Tags: java, intellij-plugin, plugin.xml

I am adding custom icon to my intellij plugin action.

```
<action icon="/video/videoicon.svg" class="actions.PopupDialogAction" description="Test Description" id="fetchSession" text="Fetch Session"/>
```

videoicon is a 16*16 custom icon.

My action toolbar doesn't show up the icon though, what am I doing wrong? (the first image which shows blank is where I want to show the icon.

I can access the icon by pressing the command + click, not sure what's wrong.

[Action Toolbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX5gF.png)

Comment: Is your image located in side `src.main.resources.video` ?

Answer (score 0):

May be if you invalidate the app cache it will reload the plugin data (not sure if it will work, but after every plugin update some restart is needed). So I will suggest to go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).